# Unloading a conan package with its required packages

Tags: conan

Is there a way to automatically upload the package created by conan and the packages on which it depends to the repository?

Example:
I have a `<package-A>` that I compiled and it is accordingly not in the repository, then I create a `<package-B>` that requires `<package-A>`

If I do `conan upload <package-B> --all -r <repository>`, then `<package-B>` will be uploading without problems, but if I then delete both packages and do `conan install <package-B> -r <repository>`, then there will be an error, because  there is neither locally nor in the repository.

***EDIT***

uilianries said right, but I want to add:

1. You need to add the `-pr` parameter to conan lock create so that it does it locally:
   `conan lock create --reference package-b/version@user/channel --lockfile-out=<lockfile-name> -pr=<profile>`
2. `conan lock build-order` does not need to be done, because it looks for dependencies not locally, but in a remote repository, you need to immediately parse the file obtained from `conan lock create ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a single command with such capability.

You will need it generate a dependencies graph, then upload one by one:

`conan lock create --reference package-b/version@user/channel`

It will generate `conan.lock` with all your dependencies graph.
Read more about [lock](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/lock.html) command.

Then, you can generate the build order from `conan.lock` into a json file:

`conan lock build-order --json build-order.json conan.lock`

Finally, you can iterate the JSON content file and upload one-by-one.

You can use `jq` or even a python script to iterate and run `conan upload`.

Another option is using Conan API, which is not public, but pretty stable.

The project [conan-package-tools](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-package-tools) uses the API to upload all dependencies [here](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-package-tools/blob/28ae68d405514364855fbdece5b22f636e802d12/cpt/runner.py#L166)

Comment: thank you, this is what I wanted, then I figured it out myself